# How to get the actual state of JobInfo?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

Similar to WorkInfo, https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo.State, how can we determine the actual state of JobInfo?

**My use case:** I have 2 jobs - Job 1 runs periodically on the charger, Job 2 runs for other various conditions (not periodic or on the charger). Both jobs update the same database. I'd like to ensure Job 1 is not actually running when Job 2 runs.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#getPendingJob(int)), it looks like I can use `getPendingJob`, but that will only tell me if the job is scheduled, and I'd like to have a better idea of what the job is doing at that given moment.

Comment: I don't know if it's the right approach, but couldn't you create a lock in your ``JobService`` and acquire/release it when Job 2 runs/finishes? A basic boolean might be enough if it's the same service instance running on the main thread

Comment: ended up using mutex lock, thanks for the suggestion